# ansible: how to iterate over all registered results?

Tags: loops, ansible

Given the following playbook:

```
---
- name: Check if log directory exists - Step 1
  stat: path="{{ wl_base }}/{{ item.0.name }}/{{ wl_dom }}/servers/{{ item.1 }}/logs" get_md5=no
  register: log_dir
  with_subelements:
    - wl_instances
    - servers

- name: Check if log directory exists - Step 2
  fail: msg="Log directory does not exists or it is not a symlink."
  failed_when: >
    log_dir.results[0].stat.islnk is not defined
    or log_dir.results[0].stat.islnk != true
    or log_dir.results[0].stat.lnk_source != "{{ wl_base }}/logs/{{ wl_dom }}/{{ item.1 }}"
  with_subelements:
    - wl_instances
    - servers
```

that is using the following vars:

```
---
wl_instances:
  - name: aservers
    servers:
      - AdminServer
  - name: mservers
    servers:
       - "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
```

the second task currently only uses one of the two possible results (`results[0]`).

My question is: how could I iterate over all available items stored in `log_dir.results`?

A sample output `debug:hostvars[inventory_hostname]` follows:

```
    "log_dir": {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "changed": false,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": "path=\"/path/to/servers/aservers/domain/AdminServer/logs\" get_md5=no",
                    "module_name": "stat"
                },
                "item": [
                    {
                        "name": "aservers"
                    },
                    "AdminServer"
                ],
                "stat": {
                    ...
                    "lnk_source": "/path/to/logs/domain/AdminServer",
                    ...
                }
            },
            {
                "changed": false,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": "path=\"/path/to/servers/mservers/domain/servers/some_hostname/logs\" get_md5=no",
                    "module_name": "stat"
                },
                "item": [
                    {
                        "name": "mservers"
                    },
                    "some_hostname"
                ],
                "stat": {
                    ...
                    "lnk_source": "/path/to/logs/domain/some_hostname",
                    ...
```

Comment: Not for the iteration, I switched to a data structure suitable for a `with_dict` iteration.

Comment: Found a solution that worked for me, posted it below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looping over the results in an array (denoted by the []), would be done as

```
with_items: somelist
```

or if it's a dict that contains a list, as in this case

```
with_items: log_dir.results
```

note this can also be written

```
with_items: log_dir['results']
```

so in your task

```
- name: Check if log directory exists - Step 2
  fail: msg="Log directory does not exists or it is not a symlink."
  failed_when: >
    item.stat.islnk is not defined
    or item.stat.islnk != true
    or item..stat.lnk_source != "{{ wl_base }}/logs/{{ wl_dom }}/{{ item.1 }}"
  with_items: log_dir.results
```

More information and examples is available in http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_loops.html#standard-loops.

The main thing here is that you're wanting to access only part of the registered variable.

Comment: Hi Halberom, thank you for answering my call for help on IRC. I had to leave IRC before I could talk to you. Found the same solution before I saw your post. I will upvote yours as the correct answer. Thanks again!

Comment: should not it be `fail: ... when: ...` instead of `fail: ... failed_when:`

Comment: quick note.   since ansible v2.2, with_items requires explicit jinja2 wrapping so this would now be

with_items: "{{ log_dir.results }}"

Answer (score 3):

My debug output:

```
{
"dkim_key.results": [
    {
        "changed": false,
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": "path=/etc/opendkim/keys/accept.example.com/mail.private get_md5=no",
            "module_name": "stat"
        },
        "item": "accept.example.com",
        "stat": {
            "atime": 1427461574.5667424,
            "checksum": "c882abaabvc66257555929f6290480a409d1",
            "ctime": 1427461575.0307424,
            "dev": 64770,
            "exists": true,
            "gid": 119,
            "inode": 521115,
            "isblk": false,
            "ischr": false,
            "isdir": false,
            "isfifo": false,
            "isgid": false,
            "islnk": false,
            "isreg": true,
            "issock": false,
            "isuid": false,
            "mode": "0600",
            "mtime": 1427461574.5947425,
            "nlink": 1,
            "pw_name": "opendkim",
            "rgrp": false,
            "roth": false,
            "rusr": true,
            "size": 887,
            "uid": 110,
            "wgrp": false,
            "woth": false,
            "wusr": true,
            "xgrp": false,
            "xoth": false,
            "xusr": false
        }
    },
    {
        "changed": false,
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": "path=/etc/opendkim/keys/test.example.com/mail.private get_md5=no",
            "module_name": "stat"
        },
        "item": "test.example.com",
        "stat": {
            "exists": false
        }
    }
]
}
```

Found the solution for a similar problem as follows:

```
- name: DKIM | Generate signing key
  shell: opendkim-genkey -s {{ postfix.dkim_selector }} -d {{ item.item }} -D /etc/opendkim/keys/{{ item.item }}
  with_items: dkim_key.results
  when: not item.stat.exists
  notify: restart opendkim
  tags:
    - postfix
    - dkim
```

Using the `dkim_key.results` and a list to iterate over and then check against that list with `item.stat.exists`. Lastly getting the actual `item`  via `item.item`